# Excel - SUM/COUNT values with a certain property that exists in a data set

Tags: excel, count, sum, conditional-statements

So, in Excel, Imagine this situation:

On Sheet1, you've a massive data set, being the columns that matter A (lets call it the groups column, identified by a number) and B (lets call it the values column). As an example:

```
GROUP    VALUES
1        3
1        2
2        -2
1        -1
3        4
2        5
```

On Sheet2, you've a table, with the group number on the A column, and on the B column, you put 0 if you don't wan't to include the group, and a value bigger than 0 if you want to include it. Example:

```
GROUP    ACTIVE
1        1
2        0
3        2 //like I said, any number bigger than 0
```

Now, on Sheet3, you want to get the sum/count of values the belong to any included group. In this example, it should return 8.

Is there any function, or combination of functions, that may help me resolve the situation above? I've tried several combinations of both COUNTIFS and SUMIFS, but to no avail...

Comment: It's unclear to me why a simple [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) or [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) isn't going to work for this. Supply some sample data together with expected results.

Comment: Added an example... Well, unless I add a criteria for each group, which taking into account the number of groups I've is pretty much unfeasable, I'm not seeing how the countif/ifs alone could help me...

Comment: How many groups you have? is the 2nd sheet hard coded?

Comment: Lets say it can be anything between 10 to 500... And the "ACTIVE" column is based on a formula which returns how many values that group has IF the Success Rate of the entire group complies with a certain condition... But I don't think this is necessary for the problem...

Comment: Make `Sheet2!C` have a `SUMIF` for the relevant group on each row, then the value want is the just the sum of `Sheet2!C`

Answer (score 0):

You are treating your workbook as a relational database with the worksheets fulfilling the roles of tables so I thought that a database style solution would be best.

```
Sub Sheets_Inner_Join()
    'Dim cnx As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnx As Object, rs As Object
    Dim sWB As String, sCNX As String, sSQL As String
    Dim ws1TBLaddr As String, ws2TBLaddr As String
    Dim vRNG As Variant

    ws1TBLaddr = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)
    ws2TBLaddr = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)

    sWB = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sCNX = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sWB _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cnx = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cnx.Open sCNX

    sSQL = "SELECT SUM(w1.[values]) FROM [Sheet1$" & ws1TBLaddr & "] w1"
    sSQL = sSQL & " INNER JOIN [Sheet2$" & ws2TBLaddr & "] w2 ON w1.[group] = w2.[group]"
    sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE w2.[active]>0"
    'Debug.Print sSQL

    rs.Open sSQL, cnx

    Sheet3.Range("A2") = CLng(rs.GetString)

    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    cnx.Close: Set cnx = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've used late binding in order that additional library references do not have to be added to the VBA project. This could easily be turned into a number of User Defined Functions for ease-of-use throughout the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer a formula solution, adjust ranges to suit:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!B2:B4>0),SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A7,Sheet2!A2:A4,Sheet1!B2:B7))
```

Comment: There's the issue that the SUMPRODUCT needs two arrays of data, and on that one, the part at the right returns a single value only, and will fire a #VALUE! error =/

Comment: It doesn't return an error for me, it returns the correct sum.  The SUMIF will return an array of values based on the criteria provided in the second argument, in this case the `Sheet2!A2:A4` (The Group numbers).  So the first part will returns 1's and 0's based on whether `Sheet2!B2:B4` is greater than 0 or not, and then multiply that by the SUMIF array

Comment: So in this case it will calculate to `{1,0,1}*{(3+2-1=4),(-2+5=3),(4=4)}` => `{1,0,1}*{4,3,4}` => `4+0+4` => `8`